# expanding vectors in numpy (Pytorch expand)

Tags: numpy, matrix, pytorch, tensor, expand

I have a B x 1 shaped numpy tensor, named `Y`.
I'm looking for the numpy equivalent for the following expansion command in Pytorch (`N` is an integer):

```
Y.expand(-1, N)[:, None]
```

Comment: What's the resulting shape supposed to be?

Comment: Based on the docs, I think `np.broadcast_to` is similar, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html

Comment: @hpaulj np.broadcast_to doesn't work with negative values

Comment: what's the significance of negative values?  What I suggest might not be a clone of the torch, but may, with the right inputs, do the same thing.  I can't test it for you.

Answer (score -1):

What about np.tile?

```
>>> B = 4
>>> N = 3
>>> a = np.arange(0, B).reshape(B, 1)
>>> np.tile(a, (1, N))
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: this is in pytorch, I'm looking for a numpy command.

Comment: Ah, I misread. I'll update the answer.